# Set MSMQ Watcher

Tags: msmq

I want to set watcher in MSMQ like as FileWatcher, It will check in the queue if message is in queue then it will deliver, i do not want to use Timer, Thread. Is there anyother way to process this?

Not finished here, it will continuously watch the queue. Using windows service and Timers i have tried its working but sometimes the time interval creates deadlock so want to ignore it.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify your question: you want something like a c# answer?

Comment: Ya, just a small guideline will also work for me :)

Comment: OK. So if I understand correctly, you want to check if there are new messages in your queue without using polling?

Comment: yes you are right without polling i want to check messages that are in queue and yes if there is some exception occures then that message will again added to the queue at last.